# Link to all Visual Studio $ variables

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, msbuild, visual-c++-6

I was having a look at `$(Configuration)`,`$(ProjectDir)` etc. in Visual Studio 2008 for Prebuild events.

Is there a link to all of these variables with a definition for each one of them?

Comment: This one is more comprehensive, but likely published at a later date, than the selected answer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reserved-and-well-known-properties?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Try this MSDN page: [Macros for Build Commands and Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=vs-2017)

Comment: Note that you may have to change the selection of the version. For instance, I have [MSVS2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), and `$(Configuration)`(in 2013) is `$(ConfigurationName)` instead.

Comment: Now if only there were a way to access these programmatically in our code (in my case C#).

Comment: @Chiramisu If you were to create a custom msbuild task you should be able to use those variables.

Comment: PSA: Microsoft only documents about 10% of the actual macros.  See ojdo's answer for a more complete list.

Answer (score 38):

Ok, I finally wanted to have a pretty complete, *searchable* list of those variables for reference. Here is a complete (OCR-generated, as I did not easily find something akin to a `printenv` command) list of defined variables for a Visual C++ project *on my machine*. Probably not all macros are defined for others (e.g. `OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE`), but I wanted to err on the side of inclusiveness here.

For example, this is the first time that I see `$(Language)` (expanding to `C++` for this project) being mentioned outside of the IDE.

```
$(AllowLocalNetworkLoopback)
$(ALLUSERSPROFILE)
$(AndroidTargetsPath)
$(APPDATA)
$(AppxManifestMetadataClHostArchDir)
$(AppxManifestMetadataCITargetArchDir)
$(Attach)
$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)
$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)
$(CharacterSet)
$(CLRSupport)
$(CommonProgramFiles)
$(CommonProgramW6432)
$(COMPUTERNAME)
$(ComSpec)
$(Configuration)
$(ConfigurationType)
$(CppWinRT_IncludePath)
$(CrtSDKReferencelnclude)
$(CrtSDKReferenceVersion)
$(CustomAfterMicrosoftCommonProps)
$(CustomBeforeMicrosoftCommonProps)
$(DebugCppRuntimeFilesPath)
$(DebuggerFlavor)
$(DebuggerLaunchApplication)
$(DebuggerRequireAuthentication)
$(DebuggerType)
$(DefaultLanguageSourceExtension)
$(DefaultPlatformToolset)
$(DefaultWindowsSDKVersion)
$(DefineExplicitDefaults)
$(DelayImplib)
$(DesignTimeBuild)
$(DevEnvDir)
$(DocumentLibraryDependencies)
$(DotNetSdk_IncludePath)
$(DotNetSdk_LibraryPath)
$(DotNetSdk_LibraryPath_arm)
$(DotNetSdk_LibraryPath_arm64)
$(DotNetSdk_LibraryPath_x64)
$(DotNetSdk_LibraryPath_x86)
$(DotNetSdkRoot)
$(DriverData)
$(EmbedManifest)
$(EnableManagedIncrementalBuild)
$(EspXtensions)
$(ExcludePath)
$(ExecutablePath)
$(ExtensionsToDeleteOnClean)
$(FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING)
$(FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING)
$(FrameworkDir)
$(FrameworkDir_110)
$(FrameworkSdkDir)
$(FrameworkSDKRoot)
$(FrameworkVersion)
$(GenerateManifest)
$(GPURefDebuggerBreakOnAllThreads)
$(HOMEDRIVE)
$(HOMEPATH)
$(IgnorelmportLibrary)
$(ImportByWildcardAfterMicrosoftCommonProps)
$(ImportByWildcardBeforeMicrosoftCommonProps)
$(ImportDirectoryBuildProps)
$(ImportProjectExtensionProps)
$(ImportUserLocationsByWildcardAfterMicrosoftCommonProps)
$(ImportUserLocationsByWildcardBeforeMicrosoftCommonProps)
$(IncludePath)
$(IncludeVersionInInteropName)
$(IntDir)
$(InteropOutputPath)
$(iOSTargetsPath)
$(Keyword)
$(KIT_SHARED_IncludePath)
$(LangID)
$(LangName)
$(Language)
$(LIBJABRA_TRACE_LEVEL)
$(LibraryPath)
$(LibraryWPath)
$(LinkCompiled)
$(LinkIncremental)
$(LOCALAPPDATA)
$(LocalDebuggerAttach)
$(LocalDebuggerDebuggerlType)
$(LocalDebuggerMergeEnvironment)
$(LocalDebuggerSQLDebugging)
$(LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory)
$(LocalGPUDebuggerTargetType)
$(LOGONSERVER)
$(MicrosoftCommonPropsHasBeenImported)
$(MpiDebuggerCleanupDeployment)
$(MpiDebuggerDebuggerType)
$(MpiDebuggerDeployCommonRuntime)
$(MpiDebuggerNetworkSecurityMode)
$(MpiDebuggerSchedulerNode)
$(MpiDebuggerSchedulerTimeout)
$(MSBuild_ExecutablePath)
$(MSBuildAllProjects)
$(MSBuildAssemblyVersion)
$(MSBuildBinPath)
$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)
$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)
$(MSBuildExtensionsPath64)
$(MSBuildFrameworkToolsPath)
$(MSBuildFrameworkToolsPath32)
$(MSBuildFrameworkToolsPath64)
$(MSBuildFrameworkToolsRoot)
$(MSBuildLoadMicrosoftTargetsReadOnly)
$(MSBuildNodeCount)
$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)
$(MSBuildProjectDefaultTargets)
$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)
$(MSBuildProjectDirectoryNoRoot)
$(MSBuildProjectExtension)
$(MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath)
$(MSBuildProjectFile)
$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)
$(MSBuildProjectName)
$(MSBuildRuntimeType)
$(MSBuildRuntimeVersion)
$(MSBuildSDKsPath)
$(MSBuildStartupDirectory)
$(MSBuildToolsPath)
$(MSBuildToolsPath32)
$(MSBuildToolsPath64)
$(MSBuildToolsRoot)
$(MSBuildToolsVersion)
$(MSBuildUserExtensionsPath)
$(MSBuildVersion)
$(MultiToolTask)
$(NETFXKitsDir)
$(NETFXSDKDir)
$(NuGetProps)
$(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS)
$(OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE)
$(OneDrive)
$(OneDriveCommercial)
$(OS)
$(OutDir)
$(OutDirWasSpecified)
$(OutputType)
$(Path)
$(PATHEXT)
$(PkgDefApplicationConfigFile)
$(Platform)
$(Platform_Actual)
$(PlatformArchitecture)
$(PlatformName)
$(PlatformPropsFound)
$(PlatformShortName)
$(PlatformTarget)
$(PlatformTargetsFound)
$(PlatformToolset)
$(PlatformToolsetVersion)
$(PostBuildEventUseInBuild)
$(PreBuildEventUseInBuild)
$(PreferredToolArchitecture)
$(PreLinkEventUselnBuild)
$(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE)
$(PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432)
$(PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER)
$(PROCESSOR_LEVEL)
$(PROCESSOR_REVISION)
$(ProgramData)
$(ProgramFiles)
$(ProgramW6432)
$(ProjectDir)
$(ProjectExt)
$(ProjectFileName)
$(ProjectGuid)
$(ProjectName)
$(ProjectPath)
$(PSExecutionPolicyPreference)
$(PSModulePath)
$(PUBLIC)
$(ReferencePath)
$(RemoteDebuggerAttach)
$(RemoteDebuggerConnection)
$(RemoteDebuggerDebuggerlype)
$(RemoteDebuggerDeployDebugCppRuntime)
$(RemoteDebuggerServerName)
$(RemoteDebuggerSQLDebugging)
$(RemoteDebuggerWorkingDirectory)
$(RemoteGPUDebuggerTargetType)
$(RetargetAlwaysSupported)
$(RootNamespace)
$(RoslynTargetsPath)
$(SDK35ToolsPath)
$(SDK40ToolsPath)
$(SDKDisplayName)
$(SDKIdentifier)
$(SDKVersion)
$(SESSIONNAME)
$(SolutionDir)
$(SolutionExt)
$(SolutionFileName)
$(SolutionName)
$(SolutionPath)
$(SourcePath)
$(SpectreMitigation)
$(SQLDebugging)
$(SystemDrive)
$(SystemRoot)
$(TargetExt)
$(TargetFrameworkVersion)
$(TargetName)
$(TargetPlatformMinVersion)
$(TargetPlatformVersion)
$(TargetPlatformWinMDLocation)
$(TargetUniversalCRTVersion)
$(TEMP)
$(TMP)
$(ToolsetPropsFound)
$(ToolsetTargetsFound)
$(UCRTContentRoot)
$(UM_IncludePath)
$(UniversalCRT_IncludePath)
$(UniversalCRT_LibraryPath_arm)
$(UniversalCRT_LibraryPath_arm64)
$(UniversalCRT_LibraryPath_x64)
$(UniversalCRT_LibraryPath_x86)
$(UniversalCRT_PropsPath)
$(UniversalCRT_SourcePath)
$(UniversalCRTSdkDir)
$(UniversalCRTSdkDir_10)
$(UseDebugLibraries)
$(UseLegacyManagedDebugger)
$(UseOfATL)
$(UseOfMfc)
$(USERDOMAIN)
$(USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE)
$(USERNAME)
$(USERPROFILE)
$(UserRootDir)
$(VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH)
$(VC_ATLMFC_IncludePath)
$(VC_ATLMFC_SourcePath)
$(VC_CRT_SourcePath)
$(VC_ExecutablePath_ARM)
$(VC_ExecutablePath_ARM64)
$(VC_ExecutablePath_x64)
$(VC_ExecutablePath_x64_ARM)
$(VC_ExecutablePath_x64_ARM64)
$(VC_ExecutablePath_x64_x64)
$(VC_ExecutablePath_x64_x86)
$(VC_ExecutablePath_x86)
$(VC_ExecutablePath_x86_ARM)
$(VC_ExecutablePath_x86_ARM64)
$(VC_ExecutablePath_x86_x64)
$(VC_ExecutablePath_x86_x86)
$(VC_IFCPath)
$(VC_IncludePath)
$(VC_LibraryPath_ARM)
$(VC_LibraryPath_ARM64)
$(VC_LibraryPath_ATL_ARM)
$(VC_LibraryPath_ATL_ARM64)
$(VC_LibraryPath_ATL_x64)
$(VC_LibraryPath_ATL_x86)
$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_ARM)
$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_ARM_Desktop)
$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_ARM_OneCore)
$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_ARM_Store)
$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_ARM64)
$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_ARM64_Desktop)
$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_ARM64_OneCore)
$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_ARM64_Store)
$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_x64)
$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_x64_Desktop)
$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_x64_OneCore)
$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_x64_Store)
$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_x86)
$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_x86_Desktop)
$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_x86_OneCore)
$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_x86_Store)
$(VC_LibraryPath_x64)
$(VC_LibraryPath_x86)
$(VC_PGO_RunTime_Dir)
$(VC_ReferencesPath_ARM)
$(VC_ReferencesPath_ARM64)
$(VC_ReferencesPath_ATL_ARM)
$(VC_ReferencesPath_ATL_ARM64)
$(VC_ReferencesPath_ATL_x64)
$(VC_ReferencesPath_ATL_x86)
$(VC_ReferencesPath_VC_ARM)
$(VC_ReferencesPath_VC_ARM64)
$(VC_ReferencesPath_VC_x64)
$(VC_ReferencesPath_VC_x86)
$(VC_ReferencesPath_x64)
$(VC_ReferencesPath_x86)
$(VC_SourcePath)
$(VC_VC_IncludePath)
$(VC_VS_IncludePath)
$(VC_VS_LibraryPath_VC_VS_ARM)
$(VC_VS_LibraryPath_VC_VS_x64)
$(VC_VS_LibraryPath_VC_VS_x86)
$(VC_VS_SourcePath)
$(VCIDEInstallDir)
$(VCIDEInstallDir_150)
$(VCInstallDir)
$(VCInstallDir_150)
$(VCLibPackagePath)
$(VCProjectVersion)
$(VCTargetsPath)
$(VCTargetsPath10)
$(VCTargetsPath11)
$(VCTargetsPath12)
$(VCTargetsPath14)
$(VCTargetsPath15)
$(VCTargetsPathActual)
$(VCTargetsPathEffective)
$(VCToolArchitecture)
$(VCToolsInstallDir)
$(VCToolsInstallDir_150)
$(VCToolsVersion)
$(VisualStudioDir)
$(VisualStudioEdition)
$(VisualStudioVersion)
$(VS_ExecutablePath)
$(VS140COMNTOOLS)
$(VSAPPIDDIR)
$(VSAPPIDNAME)
$(VSInstallDir)
$(VSInstallDir_150)
$(VsInstallRoot)
$(VSLANG)
$(VSSKUEDITION)
$(VSVersion)
$(WDKBinRoot)
$(WebBrowserDebuggerDebuggerlype)
$(WebServiceDebuggerDebuggerlype)
$(WebServiceDebuggerSQLDebugging)
$(WholeProgramOptimization)
$(WholeProgramOptimizationAvailabilityInstrument)
$(WholeProgramOptimizationAvailabilityOptimize)
$(WholeProgramOptimizationAvailabilityTrue)
$(WholeProgramOptimizationAvailabilityUpdate)
$(windir)
$(Windows81SdkInstalled)
$(WindowsAppContainer)
$(WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath)
$(WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_arm)
$(WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_arm64)
$(WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64)
$(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x86)
$(WindowsSDK_MetadataFoundationPath)
$(WindowsSDK_MetadataPath)
$(WindowsSDK_MetadataPathVersioned)
$(WindowsSDK_PlatformPath)
$(WindowsSDK_SupportedAPIs_arm)
$(WindowsSDK_SupportedAPIs_x64)
$(WindowsSDK_SupportedAPIs_x86)
$(WindowsSDK_UnionMetadataPath)
$(WindowsSDK80Path)
$(WindowsSdkDir)
$(WindowsSdkDir_10)
$(WindowsSdkDir_81)
$(WindowsSdkDir_81A)
$(WindowsSDKToolArchitecture)
$(WindowsTargetPlatformVersion)
$(WinRT_IncludePath)
$(WMSISProject)
$(WMSISProjectDirectory)
```

Where to find this list within Visual Studio:

1. Open your C++ project's dialogue *Property Pages*
2. Select *any* textual field that can use a configuration variable. (in the screenshot, I use *Target Name*)
3. On the right side of the text box, click the small combobox button and select option `<Edit...>`.
4. In the new window (here, title is *Target Name*), click on button `Macros>>`.
5. Scroll through the giant list of environment/linker/macro variables.

Motivational screenshot:

[image: Visual Studio project Property Pages with exemplary Macro variable list]

Comment: How did you generate that list?

Comment: Multiple screenshots of a dreadful dialogue with scrollable (but unselectable) text, stacked vertically in GIMP to form a giant wall of easily OCR-able text-only image. A slightly degraded (scaled-down + a little gaussian blur) PNG export fed into [tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/) led to a text file with only little (`l` to `1` and so on) manual cleanup remaining.

Comment: Can confirm those steps to generate the list work in Visual Studio 2003 and 2019 (not tested intermediate ones). In VS2003, the list contained a manageable 34 entries, but VS2019 has approximately 15 times as many which seems profligate to the point of inefficiency.

Comment: Another way to generate the list is to manually double-click each macro (which adds it to the field you are editing). Then copy the entire field to Notepad++ and `Find and Replace` "$(" to "\n$(" - you'll need to set `Search Mode` to `Extended` when you replace. A tad tedious, but does the job.

Comment: Does this list apply to C# as well?

Comment: @Reahreic definitely only in part. Keep in mind that list will vary slightly for every machine, as different SDKs and libraries probably populate this list. So without having access to VS currently, I only can advise you to follow the steps and see for yourself.

Answer (score 21):

While there does not appear to be one complete list, the following may also be helpful:

How to use Environment properties:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171459.aspx

MSBuild reserved properties:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx

Well-known item properties (not sure how these are used):
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313.aspx

Comment: All these links are now obsolete: "404 Web Site not found.".

Comment: @LaurentGiroud - They are functional for me. Maybe a locale issue? I am en-US.

Comment: @saarp it looks like this is an issue with Chrome, the sites load fine with Edge...

Answer (score 18):

If you need to find values for variables other than those standard VS macros, you could do that easily using [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). Start it, find the process your Visual Studio instance runs in, right click, **Properties** <kbd>→</kbd> **Environment.** It lists all those $ vars as key-value pairs:
[image]

Comment: These are Environment variables, not Visual Studio/MSBuild $ variables?

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore, those are both

Answer (score 4):

Nikita's answer is nice for the macros that Visual Studio sets up in its environment, but this is far from comprehensive.  (Environment variables become MSBuild macros, but not vis-a-versa.)

Slight tweak to ojdo's answer: Go to the "Pre-build event command line" in "Build Events" of the IDE for any project (where you find this in the IDE may depend on the language, i.e. C#, c++, etc.  See other answers for location.)  Post the code below into the "Pre-build event command line", then build that project.  After the build starts, you will have a "macros.txt" file in your TEMP directory with a nice list of all the macros and their values.  I based the list entirely on the list contained within ojdo's answer.  I have no idea if it is comprehensive, but it's a good start!

```
echo AllowLocalNetworkLoopback=$(AllowLocalNetworkLoopback) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo ALLUSERSPROFILE=$(ALLUSERSPROFILE) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo AndroidTargetsPath=$(AndroidTargetsPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo APPDATA=$(APPDATA) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo AppxManifestMetadataClHostArchDir=$(AppxManifestMetadataClHostArchDir) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo AppxManifestMetadataCITargetArchDir=$(AppxManifestMetadataCITargetArchDir) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo Attach=$(Attach) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo BaseIntermediateOutputPath=$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo BuildingInsideVisualStudio=$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo CharacterSet=$(CharacterSet) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo CLRSupport=$(CLRSupport) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo CommonProgramFiles=$(CommonProgramFiles) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo CommonProgramW6432=$(CommonProgramW6432) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo COMPUTERNAME=$(COMPUTERNAME) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo ComSpec=$(ComSpec) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo Configuration=$(Configuration) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo ConfigurationType=$(ConfigurationType) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo CppWinRT_IncludePath=$(CppWinRT_IncludePath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo CrtSDKReferencelnclude=$(CrtSDKReferencelnclude) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo CrtSDKReferenceVersion=$(CrtSDKReferenceVersion) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo CustomAfterMicrosoftCommonProps=$(CustomAfterMicrosoftCommonProps) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo CustomBeforeMicrosoftCommonProps=$(CustomBeforeMicrosoftCommonProps) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo DebugCppRuntimeFilesPath=$(DebugCppRuntimeFilesPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo DebuggerFlavor=$(DebuggerFlavor) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo DebuggerLaunchApplication=$(DebuggerLaunchApplication) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo DebuggerRequireAuthentication=$(DebuggerRequireAuthentication) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo DebuggerType=$(DebuggerType) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo DefaultLanguageSourceExtension=$(DefaultLanguageSourceExtension) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo DefaultPlatformToolset=$(DefaultPlatformToolset) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo DefaultWindowsSDKVersion=$(DefaultWindowsSDKVersion) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo DefineExplicitDefaults=$(DefineExplicitDefaults) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo DelayImplib=$(DelayImplib) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo DesignTimeBuild=$(DesignTimeBuild) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo DevEnvDir=$(DevEnvDir) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo DocumentLibraryDependencies=$(DocumentLibraryDependencies) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo DotNetSdk_IncludePath=$(DotNetSdk_IncludePath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo DotNetSdk_LibraryPath=$(DotNetSdk_LibraryPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo DotNetSdk_LibraryPath_arm=$(DotNetSdk_LibraryPath_arm) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo DotNetSdk_LibraryPath_arm64=$(DotNetSdk_LibraryPath_arm64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo DotNetSdk_LibraryPath_x64=$(DotNetSdk_LibraryPath_x64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo DotNetSdk_LibraryPath_x86=$(DotNetSdk_LibraryPath_x86) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo DotNetSdkRoot=$(DotNetSdkRoot) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo DriverData=$(DriverData) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo EmbedManifest=$(EmbedManifest) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo EnableManagedIncrementalBuild=$(EnableManagedIncrementalBuild) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo EspXtensions=$(EspXtensions) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo ExcludePath=$(ExcludePath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo ExecutablePath=$(ExecutablePath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo ExtensionsToDeleteOnClean=$(ExtensionsToDeleteOnClean) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING=$(FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING=$(FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo FrameworkDir=$(FrameworkDir) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo FrameworkDir_110=$(FrameworkDir_110) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo FrameworkSdkDir=$(FrameworkSdkDir) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo FrameworkSDKRoot=$(FrameworkSDKRoot) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo FrameworkVersion=$(FrameworkVersion) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo GenerateManifest=$(GenerateManifest) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo GPURefDebuggerBreakOnAllThreads=$(GPURefDebuggerBreakOnAllThreads) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo HOMEDRIVE=$(HOMEDRIVE) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo HOMEPATH=$(HOMEPATH) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo IgnorelmportLibrary=$(IgnorelmportLibrary) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo ImportByWildcardAfterMicrosoftCommonProps=$(ImportByWildcardAfterMicrosoftCommonProps) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo ImportByWildcardBeforeMicrosoftCommonProps=$(ImportByWildcardBeforeMicrosoftCommonProps) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo ImportDirectoryBuildProps=$(ImportDirectoryBuildProps) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo ImportProjectExtensionProps=$(ImportProjectExtensionProps) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo ImportUserLocationsByWildcardAfterMicrosoftCommonProps=$(ImportUserLocationsByWildcardAfterMicrosoftCommonProps) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo ImportUserLocationsByWildcardBeforeMicrosoftCommonProps=$(ImportUserLocationsByWildcardBeforeMicrosoftCommonProps) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo IncludePath=$(IncludePath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo IncludeVersionInInteropName=$(IncludeVersionInInteropName) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo IntDir=$(IntDir) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo InteropOutputPath=$(InteropOutputPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo iOSTargetsPath=$(iOSTargetsPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo Keyword=$(Keyword) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo KIT_SHARED_IncludePath=$(KIT_SHARED_IncludePath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo LangID=$(LangID) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo LangName=$(LangName) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo Language=$(Language) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo LIBJABRA_TRACE_LEVEL=$(LIBJABRA_TRACE_LEVEL) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo LibraryPath=$(LibraryPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo LibraryWPath=$(LibraryWPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo LinkCompiled=$(LinkCompiled) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo LinkIncremental=$(LinkIncremental) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo LOCALAPPDATA=$(LOCALAPPDATA) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo LocalDebuggerAttach=$(LocalDebuggerAttach) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo LocalDebuggerDebuggerlType=$(LocalDebuggerDebuggerlType) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo LocalDebuggerMergeEnvironment=$(LocalDebuggerMergeEnvironment) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo LocalDebuggerSQLDebugging=$(LocalDebuggerSQLDebugging) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory=$(LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo LocalGPUDebuggerTargetType=$(LocalGPUDebuggerTargetType) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo LOGONSERVER=$(LOGONSERVER) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MicrosoftCommonPropsHasBeenImported=$(MicrosoftCommonPropsHasBeenImported) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MpiDebuggerCleanupDeployment=$(MpiDebuggerCleanupDeployment) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MpiDebuggerDebuggerType=$(MpiDebuggerDebuggerType) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MpiDebuggerDeployCommonRuntime=$(MpiDebuggerDeployCommonRuntime) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MpiDebuggerNetworkSecurityMode=$(MpiDebuggerNetworkSecurityMode) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MpiDebuggerSchedulerNode=$(MpiDebuggerSchedulerNode) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MpiDebuggerSchedulerTimeout=$(MpiDebuggerSchedulerTimeout) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuild_ExecutablePath=$(MSBuild_ExecutablePath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildAllProjects=$(MSBuildAllProjects) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildAssemblyVersion=$(MSBuildAssemblyVersion) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildBinPath=$(MSBuildBinPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildExtensionsPath=$(MSBuildExtensionsPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildExtensionsPath32=$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildExtensionsPath64=$(MSBuildExtensionsPath64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildFrameworkToolsPath=$(MSBuildFrameworkToolsPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildFrameworkToolsPath32=$(MSBuildFrameworkToolsPath32) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildFrameworkToolsPath64=$(MSBuildFrameworkToolsPath64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildFrameworkToolsRoot=$(MSBuildFrameworkToolsRoot) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildLoadMicrosoftTargetsReadOnly=$(MSBuildLoadMicrosoftTargetsReadOnly) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildNodeCount=$(MSBuildNodeCount) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildProgramFiles32=$(MSBuildProgramFiles32) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildProjectDefaultTargets=$(MSBuildProjectDefaultTargets) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildProjectDirectory=$(MSBuildProjectDirectory) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildProjectDirectoryNoRoot=$(MSBuildProjectDirectoryNoRoot) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildProjectExtension=$(MSBuildProjectExtension) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath=$(MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildProjectFile=$(MSBuildProjectFile) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildProjectFullPath=$(MSBuildProjectFullPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildProjectName=$(MSBuildProjectName) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildRuntimeType=$(MSBuildRuntimeType) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildRuntimeVersion=$(MSBuildRuntimeVersion) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildSDKsPath=$(MSBuildSDKsPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildStartupDirectory=$(MSBuildStartupDirectory) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildToolsPath=$(MSBuildToolsPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildToolsPath32=$(MSBuildToolsPath32) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildToolsPath64=$(MSBuildToolsPath64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildToolsRoot=$(MSBuildToolsRoot) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildToolsVersion=$(MSBuildToolsVersion) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildUserExtensionsPath=$(MSBuildUserExtensionsPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MSBuildVersion=$(MSBuildVersion) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo MultiToolTask=$(MultiToolTask) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo NETFXKitsDir=$(NETFXKitsDir) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo NETFXSDKDir=$(NETFXSDKDir) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo NuGetProps=$(NuGetProps) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=$(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE=$(OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo OneDrive=$(OneDrive) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo OneDriveCommercial=$(OneDriveCommercial) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo OS=$(OS) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo OutDir=$(OutDir) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo OutDirWasSpecified=$(OutDirWasSpecified) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo OutputType=$(OutputType) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo Path=$(Path) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo PATHEXT=$(PATHEXT) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo PkgDefApplicationConfigFile=$(PkgDefApplicationConfigFile) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo Platform=$(Platform) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo Platform_Actual=$(Platform_Actual) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo PlatformArchitecture=$(PlatformArchitecture) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo PlatformName=$(PlatformName) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo PlatformPropsFound=$(PlatformPropsFound) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo PlatformShortName=$(PlatformShortName) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo PlatformTarget=$(PlatformTarget) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo PlatformTargetsFound=$(PlatformTargetsFound) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo PlatformToolset=$(PlatformToolset) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo PlatformToolsetVersion=$(PlatformToolsetVersion) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo PostBuildEventUseInBuild=$(PostBuildEventUseInBuild) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo PreBuildEventUseInBuild=$(PreBuildEventUseInBuild) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo PreferredToolArchitecture=$(PreferredToolArchitecture) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo PreLinkEventUselnBuild=$(PreLinkEventUselnBuild) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=$(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432=$(PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=$(PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo PROCESSOR_LEVEL=$(PROCESSOR_LEVEL) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo PROCESSOR_REVISION=$(PROCESSOR_REVISION) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo ProgramData=$(ProgramData) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo ProgramFiles=$(ProgramFiles) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo ProgramW6432=$(ProgramW6432) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo ProjectDir=$(ProjectDir) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo ProjectExt=$(ProjectExt) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo ProjectFileName=$(ProjectFileName) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo ProjectGuid=$(ProjectGuid) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo ProjectName=$(ProjectName) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo ProjectPath=$(ProjectPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo PSExecutionPolicyPreference=$(PSExecutionPolicyPreference) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo PSModulePath=$(PSModulePath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo PUBLIC=$(PUBLIC) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo ReferencePath=$(ReferencePath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo RemoteDebuggerAttach=$(RemoteDebuggerAttach) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo RemoteDebuggerConnection=$(RemoteDebuggerConnection) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo RemoteDebuggerDebuggerlype=$(RemoteDebuggerDebuggerlype) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo RemoteDebuggerDeployDebugCppRuntime=$(RemoteDebuggerDeployDebugCppRuntime) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo RemoteDebuggerServerName=$(RemoteDebuggerServerName) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo RemoteDebuggerSQLDebugging=$(RemoteDebuggerSQLDebugging) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo RemoteDebuggerWorkingDirectory=$(RemoteDebuggerWorkingDirectory) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo RemoteGPUDebuggerTargetType=$(RemoteGPUDebuggerTargetType) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo RetargetAlwaysSupported=$(RetargetAlwaysSupported) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo RootNamespace=$(RootNamespace) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo RoslynTargetsPath=$(RoslynTargetsPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo SDK35ToolsPath=$(SDK35ToolsPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo SDK40ToolsPath=$(SDK40ToolsPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo SDKDisplayName=$(SDKDisplayName) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo SDKIdentifier=$(SDKIdentifier) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo SDKVersion=$(SDKVersion) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo SESSIONNAME=$(SESSIONNAME) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo SolutionDir=$(SolutionDir) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo SolutionExt=$(SolutionExt) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo SolutionFileName=$(SolutionFileName) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo SolutionName=$(SolutionName) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo SolutionPath=$(SolutionPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo SourcePath=$(SourcePath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo SpectreMitigation=$(SpectreMitigation) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo SQLDebugging=$(SQLDebugging) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo SystemDrive=$(SystemDrive) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo SystemRoot=$(SystemRoot) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo TargetExt=$(TargetExt) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo TargetFrameworkVersion=$(TargetFrameworkVersion) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo TargetName=$(TargetName) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo TargetPlatformMinVersion=$(TargetPlatformMinVersion) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo TargetPlatformVersion=$(TargetPlatformVersion) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo TargetPlatformWinMDLocation=$(TargetPlatformWinMDLocation) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo TargetUniversalCRTVersion=$(TargetUniversalCRTVersion) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo TEMP=$(TEMP) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo TMP=$(TMP) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo ToolsetPropsFound=$(ToolsetPropsFound) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo ToolsetTargetsFound=$(ToolsetTargetsFound) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo UCRTContentRoot=$(UCRTContentRoot) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo UM_IncludePath=$(UM_IncludePath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo UniversalCRT_IncludePath=$(UniversalCRT_IncludePath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo UniversalCRT_LibraryPath_arm=$(UniversalCRT_LibraryPath_arm) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo UniversalCRT_LibraryPath_arm64=$(UniversalCRT_LibraryPath_arm64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo UniversalCRT_LibraryPath_x64=$(UniversalCRT_LibraryPath_x64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo UniversalCRT_LibraryPath_x86=$(UniversalCRT_LibraryPath_x86) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo UniversalCRT_PropsPath=$(UniversalCRT_PropsPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo UniversalCRT_SourcePath=$(UniversalCRT_SourcePath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo UniversalCRTSdkDir=$(UniversalCRTSdkDir) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo UniversalCRTSdkDir_10=$(UniversalCRTSdkDir_10) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo UseDebugLibraries=$(UseDebugLibraries) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo UseLegacyManagedDebugger=$(UseLegacyManagedDebugger) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo UseOfATL=$(UseOfATL) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo UseOfMfc=$(UseOfMfc) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo USERDOMAIN=$(USERDOMAIN) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=$(USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo USERNAME=$(USERNAME) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo USERPROFILE=$(USERPROFILE) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo UserRootDir=$(UserRootDir) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH=$(VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_ATLMFC_IncludePath=$(VC_ATLMFC_IncludePath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_ATLMFC_SourcePath=$(VC_ATLMFC_SourcePath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_CRT_SourcePath=$(VC_CRT_SourcePath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_ExecutablePath_ARM=$(VC_ExecutablePath_ARM) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_ExecutablePath_ARM64=$(VC_ExecutablePath_ARM64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_ExecutablePath_x64=$(VC_ExecutablePath_x64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_ExecutablePath_x64_ARM=$(VC_ExecutablePath_x64_ARM) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_ExecutablePath_x64_ARM64=$(VC_ExecutablePath_x64_ARM64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_ExecutablePath_x64_x64=$(VC_ExecutablePath_x64_x64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_ExecutablePath_x64_x86=$(VC_ExecutablePath_x64_x86) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_ExecutablePath_x86=$(VC_ExecutablePath_x86) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_ExecutablePath_x86_ARM=$(VC_ExecutablePath_x86_ARM) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_ExecutablePath_x86_ARM64=$(VC_ExecutablePath_x86_ARM64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_ExecutablePath_x86_x64=$(VC_ExecutablePath_x86_x64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_ExecutablePath_x86_x86=$(VC_ExecutablePath_x86_x86) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_IFCPath=$(VC_IFCPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_IncludePath=$(VC_IncludePath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_LibraryPath_ARM=$(VC_LibraryPath_ARM) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_LibraryPath_ARM64=$(VC_LibraryPath_ARM64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_LibraryPath_ATL_ARM=$(VC_LibraryPath_ATL_ARM) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_LibraryPath_ATL_ARM64=$(VC_LibraryPath_ATL_ARM64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_LibraryPath_ATL_x64=$(VC_LibraryPath_ATL_x64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_LibraryPath_ATL_x86=$(VC_LibraryPath_ATL_x86) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_LibraryPath_VC_ARM=$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_ARM) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_LibraryPath_VC_ARM_Desktop=$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_ARM_Desktop) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_LibraryPath_VC_ARM_OneCore=$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_ARM_OneCore) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_LibraryPath_VC_ARM_Store=$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_ARM_Store) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_LibraryPath_VC_ARM64=$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_ARM64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_LibraryPath_VC_ARM64_Desktop=$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_ARM64_Desktop) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_LibraryPath_VC_ARM64_OneCore=$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_ARM64_OneCore) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_LibraryPath_VC_ARM64_Store=$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_ARM64_Store) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_LibraryPath_VC_x64=$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_x64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_LibraryPath_VC_x64_Desktop=$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_x64_Desktop) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_LibraryPath_VC_x64_OneCore=$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_x64_OneCore) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_LibraryPath_VC_x64_Store=$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_x64_Store) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_LibraryPath_VC_x86=$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_x86) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_LibraryPath_VC_x86_Desktop=$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_x86_Desktop) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_LibraryPath_VC_x86_OneCore=$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_x86_OneCore) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_LibraryPath_VC_x86_Store=$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_x86_Store) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_LibraryPath_x64=$(VC_LibraryPath_x64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_LibraryPath_x86=$(VC_LibraryPath_x86) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_PGO_RunTime_Dir=$(VC_PGO_RunTime_Dir) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_ReferencesPath_ARM=$(VC_ReferencesPath_ARM) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_ReferencesPath_ARM64=$(VC_ReferencesPath_ARM64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_ReferencesPath_ATL_ARM=$(VC_ReferencesPath_ATL_ARM) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_ReferencesPath_ATL_ARM64=$(VC_ReferencesPath_ATL_ARM64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_ReferencesPath_ATL_x64=$(VC_ReferencesPath_ATL_x64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_ReferencesPath_ATL_x86=$(VC_ReferencesPath_ATL_x86) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_ReferencesPath_VC_ARM=$(VC_ReferencesPath_VC_ARM) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_ReferencesPath_VC_ARM64=$(VC_ReferencesPath_VC_ARM64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_ReferencesPath_VC_x64=$(VC_ReferencesPath_VC_x64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_ReferencesPath_VC_x86=$(VC_ReferencesPath_VC_x86) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_ReferencesPath_x64=$(VC_ReferencesPath_x64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_ReferencesPath_x86=$(VC_ReferencesPath_x86) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_SourcePath=$(VC_SourcePath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_VC_IncludePath=$(VC_VC_IncludePath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_VS_IncludePath=$(VC_VS_IncludePath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_VS_LibraryPath_VC_VS_ARM=$(VC_VS_LibraryPath_VC_VS_ARM) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_VS_LibraryPath_VC_VS_x64=$(VC_VS_LibraryPath_VC_VS_x64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_VS_LibraryPath_VC_VS_x86=$(VC_VS_LibraryPath_VC_VS_x86) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VC_VS_SourcePath=$(VC_VS_SourcePath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VCIDEInstallDir=$(VCIDEInstallDir) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VCIDEInstallDir_150=$(VCIDEInstallDir_150) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VCInstallDir=$(VCInstallDir) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VCInstallDir_150=$(VCInstallDir_150) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VCLibPackagePath=$(VCLibPackagePath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VCProjectVersion=$(VCProjectVersion) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VCTargetsPath=$(VCTargetsPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VCTargetsPath10=$(VCTargetsPath10) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VCTargetsPath11=$(VCTargetsPath11) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VCTargetsPath12=$(VCTargetsPath12) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VCTargetsPath14=$(VCTargetsPath14) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VCTargetsPath15=$(VCTargetsPath15) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VCTargetsPathActual=$(VCTargetsPathActual) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VCTargetsPathEffective=$(VCTargetsPathEffective) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VCToolArchitecture=$(VCToolArchitecture) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VCToolsInstallDir=$(VCToolsInstallDir) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VCToolsInstallDir_150=$(VCToolsInstallDir_150) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VCToolsVersion=$(VCToolsVersion) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VisualStudioDir=$(VisualStudioDir) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VisualStudioEdition=$(VisualStudioEdition) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VisualStudioVersion=$(VisualStudioVersion) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VS_ExecutablePath=$(VS_ExecutablePath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VS140COMNTOOLS=$(VS140COMNTOOLS) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VSAPPIDDIR=$(VSAPPIDDIR) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VSAPPIDNAME=$(VSAPPIDNAME) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VSInstallDir=$(VSInstallDir) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VSInstallDir_150=$(VSInstallDir_150) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VsInstallRoot=$(VsInstallRoot) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VSLANG=$(VSLANG) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VSSKUEDITION=$(VSSKUEDITION) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo VSVersion=$(VSVersion) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WDKBinRoot=$(WDKBinRoot) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WebBrowserDebuggerDebuggerlype=$(WebBrowserDebuggerDebuggerlype) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WebServiceDebuggerDebuggerlype=$(WebServiceDebuggerDebuggerlype) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WebServiceDebuggerSQLDebugging=$(WebServiceDebuggerSQLDebugging) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WholeProgramOptimization=$(WholeProgramOptimization) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WholeProgramOptimizationAvailabilityInstrument=$(WholeProgramOptimizationAvailabilityInstrument) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WholeProgramOptimizationAvailabilityOptimize=$(WholeProgramOptimizationAvailabilityOptimize) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WholeProgramOptimizationAvailabilityTrue=$(WholeProgramOptimizationAvailabilityTrue) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WholeProgramOptimizationAvailabilityUpdate=$(WholeProgramOptimizationAvailabilityUpdate) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo windir=$(windir) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo Windows81SdkInstalled=$(Windows81SdkInstalled) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WindowsAppContainer=$(WindowsAppContainer) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath=$(WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_arm=$(WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_arm) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_arm64=$(WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_arm64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64=$(WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x86=$(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x86) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WindowsSDK_MetadataFoundationPath=$(WindowsSDK_MetadataFoundationPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WindowsSDK_MetadataPath=$(WindowsSDK_MetadataPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WindowsSDK_MetadataPathVersioned=$(WindowsSDK_MetadataPathVersioned) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WindowsSDK_PlatformPath=$(WindowsSDK_PlatformPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WindowsSDK_SupportedAPIs_arm=$(WindowsSDK_SupportedAPIs_arm) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WindowsSDK_SupportedAPIs_x64=$(WindowsSDK_SupportedAPIs_x64) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WindowsSDK_SupportedAPIs_x86=$(WindowsSDK_SupportedAPIs_x86) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WindowsSDK_UnionMetadataPath=$(WindowsSDK_UnionMetadataPath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WindowsSDK80Path=$(WindowsSDK80Path) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WindowsSdkDir=$(WindowsSdkDir) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WindowsSdkDir_10=$(WindowsSdkDir_10) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WindowsSdkDir_81=$(WindowsSdkDir_81) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WindowsSdkDir_81A=$(WindowsSdkDir_81A) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WindowsSDKToolArchitecture=$(WindowsSDKToolArchitecture) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WindowsTargetPlatformVersion=$(WindowsTargetPlatformVersion) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WinRT_IncludePath=$(WinRT_IncludePath) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WMSISProject=$(WMSISProject) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
echo WMSISProjectDirectory=$(WMSISProjectDirectory) >>$(TEMP)\macros.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

For c#, there's no Property Pages.

You can see a very limited list in Project Properties, Build Events, Edit Pre-build, Macros>> as mentioned in [Is there a list of Visual Studio environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1460798/1948625)

Another way is to **set the MSBuild output verbosity to Diagnostic**, as explained for the command line in https://techblog.dorogin.com/msbuild-a-simple-way-to-find-out-all-properties-and-their-values-while-building-a-csproj-file-d14bcbe8fadc or here:
[image: Options, Projects and Solutions, Build and Run dialog]

The macros and variables seem to be output many times. As an example, in my solution, "SolutionPath" is shown 82 times! Look for the text "Initial Properties:". Mine has about 780 properties, and I have no idea if they can all be used.

Unfortunately, I still can't see the value of `$(VSInstalledExternalTools)` as used by Options, Projects and Solutions, Web Package Management, External Web Tools! I'm thinking it means it's undefined:
[image: Options, Projects and Solutions, Web Package Management, External Web Tools dialog]

Answer (score 1):

Anybody working on legacy software using Visual Studio 6.0 will find that 
 $(Configuration) and $(ProjectDir) macro's are not defined. For post-build/pre-build events, give a relative path starting with the location of your .dsw file(workspace) as the starting point. In [relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895457/how-to-define-relative-paths-in-visual-studio-project) dot represents the current directory and .. represents the parent directory. Give a relative path to the file that need to be processed. Example:
 ( copy /y .\..\..\Debug\mylib.dll  .\..\MyProject\Debug\ )

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers, note that [property sheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx#Anchor_0) can be configured for the project, creating custom project-specific parameters.

To access or create them navigate to(at least in Visual Studio 2013) **View -> Other Windows -> Property Manager**. You can also find them in the source folder as **.prop** files