# Is there a list of Visual Studio environment variables?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Link to all Visual Studio $ variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830271/link-to-all-visual-studio-variables)

Visual Studio has a lot of environment variables like $(TargetFileName) but I can't seem to find a list of all of them on MSDN or via Google.

Does such a list exist?

NOTE: See the top answer for the duplicate question (link above) for a link to a list on MSDN.

Comment: Those are actually called "macros". Visual Studio also provides some environment variables but they are accessed and named differently.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In most places where you can use those, there's a "Macros" button or similar, which shows all available macros and the current value of them. For example, go to the PostBuild event editor to find the list.

Edit: I just checked. [There's a list in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx).

Comment: PS: this is the same list as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/830307/2707864). Quite useful.

Answer (score 39):

You can get the list of available environment variables directly **within Visual Studio 2010** with the following steps:

1. in Visual Studio env, *right click on your project*
2. *properties*
3. *configuration properties* / *C++* / *General*
4. for ex. go into *Additional Include directories*
5. 'dropdown' *Edit*
6. *Macros*

There you will find a complete list of available macros **with their values set according to your settings**. This can be very useful when debugging or selecting the right macro for your project settings.

Comment: In Visual Studio Premium 2013 (at least when I am using c#) the click path given here does not exist. Clicking the "Macros >>" button as noted by @OregonGhost works and gives the "available macros **with their values set according to your settings**".