# Is there a list of variables that can be used in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am setting up a project in VS 2010 based on this guide:

http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Setting+Up+An+Application+-+Visual+Studio

At some point I need to specify a path like this:

```
$(OGRE_HOME)\lib\$(Configuration)
```

I have created the variable `OGRE_HOME` myself, but what is `$(Configuration)`? Is that some existing variable defined in VS 2010?

The same goes for:

```
$(OutDir)
$(TargetFileName)
$(ProjectName).exe
```

Where can I find info on those variables, or what can be used as variables in VS 2010?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a list of Visual Studio environment variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460798/is-there-a-list-of-visual-studio-environment-variables)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx) is a list of pre-defined environment variables on MSDN.