# Visual Studio 2008: Evaluate configuration macro variables (with Intel Fortran)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, configuration

I am using MS Visual Studio 2008.

I want to configure the Working Directory of my projects, and other directories. I found [the list of available macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs%28v=vs.90%29.aspx#feedback) for this purpose.

Is there a practical way to evaluate the value of these macros?

---

PS: I am developing with Intel Visual Fortran Compiler XE 12.0 update 4, but this is possibly irrelevant for my question.

PS2: see also

[Link to all Visual Studio $ variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830271/link-to-all-visual-studio-variables)

[Is there a list of Visual Studio environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460798/is-there-a-list-of-visual-studio-environment-variables)

[How/Where are the environment variables in a Visual Studio C++ project set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848565/how-where-are-the-environment-variables-in-a-visual-studio-c-project-set)

Answer (score 0):

Best option found so far (it can be *much* improved):

Right click on the project. Then `Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Build Events -> Pre-Build Event` and edit the `Command Line` field. Add one

```
echo {VarName} = $({VarName})
```

line for each `{VarName}` that one wants to evaluate. Cons:

1. There are [far fewer macro variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) available for pre-build events than for other configurations.
2. If no build is triggered, then the pre-build event commands are not executed. So, a build has to be at least initiated for the dump to be obtained.
3. The pre-build event is launched for every subsequent build (until removal of the command line?).

This can hardly meet the qualifier "practical", but is more practical than nothing.
Thus, I am still waiting for better answers...

Comment: how would you then access the values? I followed your procedure and tried opening the Buildlog.htm but found nothing new...

Comment: @user32882 - I do not code in that IDE anymore, since a long time ago. And I do not have it available for trying either. So, I wouldn´t know the answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can see their values using the UI. In project properties, go to e.g. the Output Directory input field, select Edit in the dropdown, then press the [Macros>>] button. Unfortunately you can't easily copy the values for automated processing, but you can easily inspect them.

Comment: In the Output Directory input field I can only type. There is no dropdown list. Perhaps this is a peculiarity of my version (NSVS2008, ver 9.0.21022.8, with .NET v3.5 SP1).

Comment: If you're in C++ project properties, a dropdown arrow should display when you start editing any field that can evaluate macros. If that doesn't happen for you, then I suspect you are either using the wrong type of project or in the regular property sheet instead of the project properties dialog.

Comment: I have only Intel(R) Visual Fortran project types available for creation. Among them, I selected Console Application, Empty Project. Perhaps that is the source of the difference. What is "the regular property sheet"?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have Fortran installed so I can't check, but you're probably right that it doesn't support that feature for whatever reason. The "regular property sheet" is what you get when you press Alt-Enter (or choose View -> Properties Window).