# Cannot locate certain Microsoft Build command Macro definitions

Tags: visual-c++, build, visual-studio-macros

I am working on some legacy Visual C++ projects, trying to bring the code and libraries up to the present day, and am getting a flood of link errors.  In my investigation into the problem, I am trying to determine where the values for many of the build command macros are coming from.  I have seen the answers in questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460798/is-there-a-list-of-visual-studio-environment-variables), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830271/link-to-all-visual-studio-variables), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848565/how-where-are-the-environment-variables-in-a-visual-studio-c-project-set), however they all seem to lead back to the same [incomplete list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx) at Microsoft, and I have been unable to find the missing macro values.

The project contains several different path reference variables, such as $(VC_LibraryPath_x86), $(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x86), and others, which are not listed on the Microsoft page linked above.

If anyone can help me "fill in the blanks" and complete the list that Microsoft left incomplete (or perhaps they are on a much older list that is not on their site any more), that would be a great help.

Thanks.

Comment: You should specify a particular VC version, since this kept changing between versions. For example `VC_LibraryPath_x86` and `WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x86` didn't exist in VC 2010.

Comment: To list the macros in effect see for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/12056067.

Comment: @dxiv, You are correct, the projects were created long ago in VC++ 6.0, and, while we have multiple versions of newer Visual Studios to choose from, other projects are currently in 2010 so the policy is to keep the updated projects in 2010 (not my decision to make, but I can make recommendations...)