# Change relative path in VIsual Studio Professional 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, relative-path

When I run tests in Visual Studio I have a test folder containing testdata. To reach these I use

```
File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine("testData", "input.html"));
```

But instead of looking in the project folder where the testdata is located 
    `C:\repos\myproject\testdata`

Visual studio tries to find the file in

```
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\testData\input.html`
```

Which results in the following error:

```
`Message: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException : Could not find a part of the 
path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\testData\input.html'.`
```

Since we are several people working with the same project we need to use relative paths. Where can I change the relative path that VS is using? I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2017.

I have tried the first solution in

[How to define relative paths in Visual Studio Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895457/how-to-define-relative-paths-in-visual-studio-project)

but both the solution and project property page is different in VS Pro 2017.

Images:

[Solution properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itExK.png)

[Project properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViaoR.png)

Comment: is it a web app or desktop app?

Comment: you can use System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, filepath); for getting relative path.

Comment: Always use the full path of a file to avoid Environment.CurrentDirectory accidents like this.  c:\foo\bar\baz.ext.  Consider getting the c:\foo\bar part from Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location

Comment: If you're running your unit tests in Visual Studio, you might be able to use [`[DeploymentItem]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute.aspx)