# Visual Studio cannot find header file

Tags: c++

I am trying to use https://github.com/simple2d/simple2d with Visual Studio. I've installed it and all the headers files and built lib is present in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\simple2d`

I've then added the following path to my visual studio project settings (in the "Properties" -> "C/C++" -> "Additional include") `%LOCALAPPDATA%\simple2d`:

[image: image1]

However when I type `#include <simple2d.h>` I still get an error saying that the file is not found:

[image: image2]

What's wrong? Here's the content of `%LOCALAPPDATA%\simple2d:`

[image: image3]

**EDIT:** here is the VS commandline version to compile a "simple2d" project. Any insight to fix the problem with VS GUI? 
`cl triangle.c /I %LOCALAPPDATA%\simple2d /link /LIBPATH %LOCALAPPDATA%\simple2d\simple2d.lib /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`

Comment: Maybe you only applied this setting to Release. Instead of all configurations.

Comment: I am not sure if Environment Variables can be used in this way also. I think you need to use `$(LOCALAPPDATA)` instead of `%LOCALAPPDATA%` [https://stackoverflow.com/a/54628769/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54628769/487892)

Comment: @drescherjm I've set it on "All configurations". Still not working

Comment: @drescherjm I also tried with the direct path i.e "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\simple2d"

Comment: AppData is originally a hidden folder, it might be realted to that.

Comment: @anastaciu tried changing path, still not working

Comment: Does the project compile? I ask because this could be simply a problem with the cache that Intellisense uses.