# Visual Studio $(Variable) for nuget root path?

Tags: nuget, csproj

I use a third-party `nuget` package that contains a content file that appears in my project which I'd like to copy to my output folder. Said and done.

Unfortunately what the project file then does is this:

```
<Content Update="C:\Users\djdoe\.nuget\packages\thirdpartynuget\1.0.2\contentFiles\any\net472\thefile.txt">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

I tried

```
<Content Update="%userprofile%\.nuget
```

but then it won't copy the file. Is there a way to configure the reference with a $ variable that Visual Studio will understand?

Edit: Thanks to [Marnix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77110180/visual-studio-variable-for-nuget-root-path#comment135936153_77110180) I found two variables pointing to the nuget folder:

`$(NuGetPackageFolders)`

`$(NuGetPackageRoot)`

Both of them work for me

Comment: Would this list help you out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830271/link-to-all-visual-studio-variables

Comment: @Marnix Actually it does. There seem to be two of them `$(NuGetPackageFolders)` and `$(NuGetPackageRoot)` both of which work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What you probably want is a feature in NuGet called [`GeneratePathProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002999#generatepathproperty). It lets you opt into generating MSBuild Properties you can use for your own scripts.

Do note however that the source NuGet package could also specify that the file is supposed to be copied to the output directory. See [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/nuget-contentfiles-demystified/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002999#other-options) for an explanation.

To use the generated MSBuild property, you can do the following:

```
<Project>
  ...
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- specify GeneratePathProperty on the package reference -->
    <PackageReference Include="Third.Party.Package"
      Version="1.0.2"
      GeneratePathProperty="True" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Use the generated property ("Pkg" + msbuild-friendly package name) -->
    <Content Update="$(PkgThird_Party_Package)\contentFiles\any\net472\thefile.txt"
      CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```